# VS Code debug async code in Node JS

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Have client-server app. Debugging client module with **VS Code - Debugger for Chrome**  just fine.
In server module cannot set breakpoint on a line with **await** expression. Also cannot get value from await expression later in a code on a breakpoint.

Launch configuration:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "NODE Attach",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "restart": true,
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/.compiled/*.js" ]
 }
```

package.json:

```
....
"dev-server": "nodemon --inspect src/server/index.js --exec babel-node",
"compile": "babel --plugins transform-runtime --presets es2015 src/server --out-dir .compiled --source-maps --watch"
....
```

Any ideas?